# R: write_csv without messing up the language

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, readr

I am working with a dataset that contains data in multiple languages.

Is there a way to export my work as a CSV file and have R maintain the use of characters in a foreign language instead of replacing them with gibberish English symbols?

Comment: You can look at "file encoding".

Answer (score 2):

Update for anyone who reaches this by Google:

It looks like R only *pretends* to screw up foreign languages. When you use write_csv, it actually does create a .csv that uses the correct foreign characters.

*However*, you'll only see them if you open them in Notepad. If you open it in Excel, Excel will screw it up, and if you open it with read_csv, R will screw it up (but will still export it correctly when you use write_csv again).

Answer (score 1):

`write_excel_csv()` from the `readr` package seems to work without messing up the foreign characters when opening with Excel.